# asp.net C# Controls not visible in IE 7, 8

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I have developed an application where I have used controls such as drop down and others. But I am not able to see them when I am using IE 7, 8. Any suggestion as to whats the problem.?

Comment: which asp.net framework you are using for this?

Comment: @jalpesh : asp.net 4.0

Comment: Are you using HTML5 controls?

Comment: @jalpesh : No, asp controls.

Comment: can you post your code here?